# AngularJS how to bind maps

Tags: binding, controller, scope, angularjs

Here is my HTML:

```
<div ng-app="angularApp">
    <div ng-controller="testCtrl">
        testKey = {{testKey}}<br />
        Test 1: <input type="text" ng-model="test.myKey" />{{test[testKey]}}<br />

        Test 2: <input type="text" ng-model="test[testKey]" />{{test[testKey]}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the js:

```
angular.module('angularApp', []);

function testCtrl($scope)
{
    $scope.testKey = "myKey";
}​
```

I setup and example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/tadchristiansen/cZVAt/3/)

Why does Test 1 work but Test 2 not work? Are "[" not allowed in the ng-model directive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/cZVAt/4/) a working example. The problem is very simple, `test.[testKey]` isn't valid, you want `test[testKey]`. And you need to define `test` as an object on the controller because you cannot set a property of an undefined variable.

Comment: That was a typo. Sorry about that. I have updated the html. The jsFiddle example doesn't have that and it still does not work. Your example does because it creates an object. That is what fixed it. Why do I have to create the object with Test 2 but not Test 1. This is a dumbed down version of my current issue. My real ng-model looks like "currentCourse.translations[locale].title" and I would prefer not to have to create the object if possible (because I don't want to hard code all the locales). Perhaps it's not possible. Thoughts?

Comment: Maybe this can be considered a bug. Maybe you can create a directive to ensure that a certain 'key path' exists. `ensure-existence="currentCource.translations[locale]"`, if not exists it create all the path as objects.